# Data type warning when initializing pointers

Tags: c, xcode

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around pointers in C, coming from front-end developing this not an entirely easy endeavour. I'm following [this tutorial](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/scotty.htm), and everything is running smoothly until I try to compile the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int **ramon;
    int *paul;
    int melissa = 5;
    paul = &melissa;
    ramon = &paul;
    printf("ramon = %d\n", ramon); // <- warning: format '%d' expects type 'int'...
    printf("&paul = %d\n", &paul); // <- warning: format '%d' expects type 'int'...
    printf("*ramon = %d\n", *ramon); // <- warning: format '%d' expects type 'int'...
    printf("&melissa = %d\n", &melissa); <- warning: format '%d' expects type 'int'...
    printf("**ramon = %d\n", **ramon);p1); <- warning: format '%d' expects type 'int'...
    return(0);  
}
```

From the first printf line I get this error: "warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int **'"

I reckon this has to do with the way I initialize my pointers, but standing at the bottom of a steep learning curve I don't know how to progress. What is wrong, how do I initialize pointers to avoid the warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer initialization looks correct.  The problem is that you are trying to print a variable of type `int**` (i.e. a "pointer to a pointer to an `int`") using the `%d` format specifier which is for `int` values.

**Print `int` value**

If you want to print the value of `melissa` (i.e. 5) which is essentially what `ramon` is indirectly pointing to, you need to de-reference the pointer value the correct number of times.

De-referencing pointers is done via the `*` operator, and it essentially means "the value at which this pointer is pointing to".

- De-referencing it once (i.e. `*ramon`) will get the `int*` value which `ramon` is pointing to.
- De-referencing it a second time will get the `int` value which the de-referenced `int*` value is pointing to.
- You can chain together de-reference operators like so to get what you want:

  `printf("ramon = %d\n", **ramon);`

**Print pointer value**

If you want to print a pointer (i.e. memory location) value, you can use the `%p` format specifier.  This will print the memory address out in hex:

```
printf("ramon = %p\n", ramon); // Print the "pointer to the pointer to melissa"
printf("ramon = %p\n", *ramon); // Print the "pointer to melissa"
```

Answer (score 1):

ramon isn't an int, it's a pointer to a pointer to an int. **ramon would be an int. You're trying to print a bunch of ints with %d, but you're mostly trying to print pointers which uses the format %p.

Answer (score 1):

read `man printf`.  It is not clear whether you want to print the value pointed to by `ramon` or the actual value of `ramon` which is an address of an pointer to an int.  Same for other warnings as well.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `ramon` is an `int **`, and the `%d` specifier expects an `int`. `*ramon` will be of type `int *`, and `**ramon` will be the desired `int`.

If you want to print the pointer itself, use the `%p` specifier.

Answer (score 1):

`ramon` and `paul` are pointers and the `printf` format specifier for printing values of pointers themselves (not what they're pointing to) is `%p`. Try

```
printf("ramon = %p\n", ramon);
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning has nothing to do with how you are initializing your pointers, it has to do with the mismatch in types between `printf`'s `%d` specifier and the types you are passing to it.

If you want to print a pointer, use `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `ramon` of type "pointer to pointer to type int". i.e. it holds an address to a "pointer to type int". `%d` on the other hand is the format specifier for `int` which is why you are getting the errors.  Instead try the following:

```
printf("&paul = %p\n", ramon);     //print the address that ramon points to
printf("&melissa = %p\n", *ramon); //print the address that paul points to
printf("&melissa = %p\n", paul);   //same as above
printf("melissa = %d\n", **ramon); //print the contents of melissa
printf("melissa = %d\n", *paul);   //same as above
printf("melissa = %d\n", melissa); //same as above
```

#### Output

```
&paul = 0xbf8072f4
&melissa = 0xbf8072f0
&melissa = 0xbf8072f0
melissa = 5
melissa = 5
melissa = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

> I reckon this has to do with the way I initialize my pointers

Why would you reckon that when the error message says nothing about initialization? Read it again:

```
"warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int **'"
```

You have `%d` in the format string for your `printf()` call, as a placeholder for the value that you want to print. `%d` is used as a placeholder for values that are `int` s. The value you want to print is `ramon`. That variable has the type `int**`. The type `int` and the type `int**` are not the same.

If you want to print a pointer, then you should write the format string so as to expect a pointer. We format pointers with `%p`.

> but standing at the bottom of a steep learning curve I don't know how to progress.

The way to progress is to read the error and/or warning messages and attempt to understand them. The error messages are talking about types. You should not be trying to do anything with pointers if you haven't first got your head around the concept that values have a type (i.e., what kind of thing they are).